# OpenCV random forest CvRTrees error

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, random-forest

I got this error while using random forest inside OpenCV:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (5273-th value of 220-th (ordered) variable (=-1.70141e+38) is too large) in CvDTreeTrainData::set_data, file /home/XXX/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/ml/src/tree.cpp, line 551
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/XXX/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/ml/src/tree.cpp:551: error: (-5) 5273-th value of 220-th (ordered) variable (=-1.70141e+38) is too large in function CvDTreeTrainData::set_data

Aborted (core dumped)
```

It is strange because the printed number is not out of the float range 
(-3.4E+38 to +3.4E+38)

I found out where is printed in the source of opencv, but I'm not able to understand what's the problem:

the file is tree.cpp

```
for( i = 0; i < sample_count; i++ )
        {
            float val = ord_nan;
            int si = sidx ? sidx[i] : i;
            if( !mask || !mask[(size_t)si*m_step] )
            {
                if( idata )
                    val = (float)idata[(size_t)si*step];
                else
                    val = fdata[(size_t)si*step];

                if( fabs(val) >= ord_nan )
                {
                    sprintf( err, "%d-th value of %d-th (ordered) "
                        "variable (=%g) is too large", i, vi, val );
                    CV_ERROR( CV_StsBadArg, err );
                }
                num_valid++;
            }

            if (is_buf_16u)
                udst[i] = (unsigned short)i; // TODO: memory corruption may be here
            else
                idst[i] = i;
            _fdst[i] = val;

        }
```

Can anyone give me an hint?

Comment: There might be an error in your post because you are showing line ~400 however your error message indicates line 551.

Comment: You are right, but the code is taken from the internet and I also checked the sources of opencv copiled on my machine and it is the same. However thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check line 551 in the tree.cpp file you can see that `fabs(val) >= ord_nan` is required where  `ord_nan = FLT_MAX*0.5f`. So it is fails when `val == -1.70141e+38` since it is bigger than this limit.

Comment: Yes but if you look at the error the problem is the: if(val==INT_MAX), looking deeply yesterday night, I realized that the problem is probably that this code has been ported to linux from windows, so maybe the calculations made before uses different float precision.

Comment: @Bacci I don't think you are right. The error messages are different! If `if(val==INT_MAX)` were to fail the error message would be "...-th (categorical) variable ..." as you have included in your post (line 418). But the error message you receive is "...-th (ordered) variable ...", which is on line 549. They do not match.